# how to add multiple records from the same text box into db

Tags: php, html, sql, database

i have this small project and its simple 
1 data entry item code and date
2 read the date and edit later

thats it

now i want to make bulk add like
big text area i add item number and go next line i add next code etc without , or anything just simple enter to go next line

now how to update the database to read each line alone and make new record for each line and add date also

ill show you

```
$txtitemcode=$_POST['itemcode'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$_POST['date'] = $date;

$sql="INSERT INTO dba(itemcode,date) VALUES ('".$txtitemcode."','".$date."')";
```

and this the main box

```
<html>
<body>
<form action=add.php method=POST>
<table border=0 align=center bgcolor="#99FF00">
<tr>
<td>ITEM CODE</td><td><textarea input type="text" rows="20" cols="50" name="itemcode" /></textarea></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan=2 align=center><input type=submit value=add><input type=reset value=cancel>
</table>
```

thank you

Comment: Why don't u just use a special character instead of new line and than identify according to that...??

Comment: im not sure how to make that and if i did i will be stuck with the same problem i cant find way to update db

Comment: Explode on a `newline` character, then use a `for each` loop and insert or use multiquery to insert multiple queries at once. And make sure to use `mysqli_*`

Comment: posted an answe... @Don check hope so that will work for u..

Answer (score 1):

Okay use any special character to differentiate records in text area.. I am assuming you used "@" sign in textarea.... after each record you put @ sign...

**Like:**

```
121@131@141@125@111@111@100@007
```

**PHP CODE WILL BE LIKE THIS THAN:**

This is your form data you getting...

```
$txtitemcode= $_POST['itemcode'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$_POST['date'] = $date;

$dataexplode = explode("@",$txtitemcode);

foreach ($dataexplode as $multipledata)
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO dba(itemcode,date) VALUES ('".$multipledata."','".$date."')";
}
```

Hope so this will work for you...

Comment: i try that bro it show errors im not sure how im gonna fix this

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\AppServ\www\system\add.php on line 12
Error:Query was empty

Comment: Than your textarea name must be something else not $_POST['itemcode'].. just check your fields name.. code will work perfect

Comment: i try that still same error, i almost try everything